# LibGDX JSON error: JSON standard does not allow identifiers

Tags: json, android-studio, libgdx, skin, scene2d

I copied and pasted a uiskin.json file to use for Scene2D UI, but for some reason my code is still crashing. **Here is the uiskin.json file that's giving me the error: JSON standard does not allow identifiers**. This is stored in my asset folder along with the default.fnt, uiskin.atlas, and uiskin.png

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
  green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
  white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
  red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
  black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
  dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
  default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
  toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
  default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
  toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
  default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
  default: {
    font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
    scrollStyle: default,
    listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
  }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
  default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
  default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
  default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
  dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
  default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
  default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
  default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
  default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
  default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
  default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
  default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
  default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: selection, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
  default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
  default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
},
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tooltip$TooltipStyle: {
  default: {
    label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    background: default-pane
  }
},
}
```

Also, this is the Java code that I have so far. Just a simple add button for reference if anyone need.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Skin skin;
    private TextField username, password;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

        final TextButton button = new TextButton("Click Me", skin, "default");
        button.setWidth(200);
        button.setHeight(50);

        stage.addActor(button);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 14 of your JSON is missing a name.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, it was just a typo on my part when I was putting it into stackoverflow. The file in my program does have that name there, and still it is crashing because it says that file can't be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooltip is a new feature from libgdx it only exists on the nightly build so you don't have it you probably copied that from the github from libgdx and you can check [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/0ee20b92ecda6b944023ac34b3b13cc407a3df1c) that it was added 9 days ago. I checked in my recently installed libgdx and tooltip isn't there, if you try to import it.

Basically remove:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tooltip$TooltipStyle: {
  default: {
    label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    background: default-pane
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that. This totally fixes my problem.

Comment: Good :) best of luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, not with uiskin.json copied from the wiki. (the real example). Did some googling, ended up on a different question (different topic) and I saw the json had double quotes (`"`) around the names and attributes.

So instead of:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
```

do:

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": { "default-font": { "file": "default.fnt" } },
```

Adding double quotes around all the names removed the `Json standard does not allow identifiers` error. No clue if it works without double quotes at runtime, as it causes an error in the json file.